# Express - How to validate file input with express-validator?

Tags: validation, express

I am using express-validator for validation. In my controller I have a method for adding new pictures to the database. Here is my code:

```
function createPicture(req, res) {

req.checkBody('title', `The title can't be empty.`).notEmpty();
req.checkBody('image', 'You must select an image.').notEmpty();

let errors = req.validationErrors();

if (errors) {
    res.json({errors: errors});
} else { ... }
```

The code works for the title field however no matter if I select an image or not - I still get a validation error about it. How can I validate file input? I just want it to be required.

Comment: There is an npm package that can be used for file validation [@thesameeric/fileguard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@thesameeric/fileguard)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same problem, the below code will not work since express-validator only validates **strings**

```
req.checkBody('title', 'The title can\'t be empty.').notEmpty();

req.checkBody('image', 'You must select an image.').notEmpty();
```

You'll need to write a custom validator, express-validator allows for this, okay this is an example of one

```
//requiring the validator
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
//the app use part
app.use(expressValidator({
customValidators: {
    isImage: function(value, filename) {

        var extension = (path.extname(filename)).toLowerCase();
        switch (extension) {
            case '.jpg':
                return '.jpg';
            case '.jpeg':
                return '.jpeg';
            case  '.png':
                return '.png';
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
}}));
```

To use the custom validator, do this first to make sure empty files will not throw undefined error:

```
restLogo = typeof req.files['rest_logo'] !== "undefined" ? req.files['rest_logo'][0].filename : '';
```

Finally to use your custom validator:

```
req.checkBody('rest_logo', 'Restaurant Logo - Please upload an image JPEG, PNG or GIF').isImage(restLogo);
```

Thanks for your question, hope this will help someone

Comment: This was some time ago and I went for a custom solution as well. Thanks for the answer! I will add this piece of code to my custom validators so I can validate file input easily via express-validator.

Answer (score 10):

In order to validate a file input field you could use **[multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#usage)**: middleware that adds a body object and a file object to the request object.
And then use **express-validator [.custom()](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/validation-chain-api.html#customvalidator)** validation function chained to your validation middleware.

With multer the user inputs are accessible through `req.file` for the file input field  and `req.body`for the other input fields (if there is any).

`req.file` will return an object containing the 6 following fields: (example for a pdf)

```
{
  fieldname: 'fileInputFieldName',
  originalname: 'uploaded_file.pdf',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'application/pdf',
  buffer: <Buffer 2 ... 192685 more bytes>,
  size: 192735
}
```

Let's say you only want to accept pdf files:
you could validate against the mimetype of the uploaded file, (which is accessible with: `req.file.mimetype`):

```
// express-validator import
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator'); 

// multer import and setup
const multer = require('multer');
const storage = multer.memoryStorage(); // Holds a buffer of the file in memory
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });


exports.post_file = [
// multer middleware
upload.single('fileInputFieldName'),


// express-validator middleware
check('fileInputFieldName')
.custom((value, {req}) => {
        if(req.file.mimetype === 'application/pdf'){
            return '.pdf'; // return "non-falsy" value to indicate valid data"
        }else{
            return false; // return "falsy" value to indicate invalid data
        }
    })
.withMessage('Please only submit pdf documents.'), // custom error message that will be send back if the file in not a pdf. 


// process the request with validated user inputs
(res, req, next) => {
    ...
    ...
}
]
```

Comment: check your code, you are using the `.single` middleware so you should access the file with `req.file` not `req.files`.